# Magento Multi Language switch not showing page

Tags: php, magento, url, multilingual

I have one web site and 2 different languages store views using magento 1.9.02.When I switch to second language from main language page has been appeared blank.

I checked url rewrites and store code url on adming page and everything is YES.
Also I cleaned cache.

Here is my basically issue;
www.cherryconcept.com/en  ( Working is fine )
www.cherryconcept.com/tr   (When I switch this language page is blank ,no appear web site).

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: Please check the error log file of server or check the run time memory.